# Windows Phone 8 with Caliburn Micro dialog approach

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I am writing a Windows Phone 8 app that manages jobs. I am using Caliburn Micro for MVVM duties.

Simplified overview: Page 1 shows a list of jobs. User selects a job. App shows relevant page - either page 2 for job type "Clean Dishes" or page 3 for job type "Vacuum Floor". All pages are view models.

So far so good.

The user can also press a plus button to add a new job. I need to show a list of job types to determine whether to show page 2 or page 3.

I would prefer that the job type list be a view model. If I make it a page it gets put in the back stack which I don't want. I don't know how to display a user control based view model from within a page. This is a port of a WPF app and there I would use WindowManager to display a view model in a modal dialog.

Options

1. Make job type list a page and remove it from the back stack when page2/3 is closed
2. Make job type list a user control. How to display from page 1?
3. Other option.

Has anyone overcome a similar issue? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your job type list in its own page and remove it from the back stack. Just add some code to `OnNavigatedFrom` event

```cs
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e) {
  base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
  NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
}
```

This will cause it be removed from the back stack when you navigate to either page 2 or page 3.

Comment: Looks promising. Will give it a try.

Comment: Works well. Here is a nice article that shows how to do it in a more Caliburn way: http://www.markermetro.com/2012/02/technical/windows-phone-removing-pages-from-the-back-stack-with-caliburn-micro/